# ASP.NET loosing connection to database when multiple users access page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, session

I have a seat reservation page on my web site. The page uses an UpdatePanel to refresh the seat's status every 5 seconds with a SQL query. That way the users should be able to see when someone else reserves a seat.

The problem is that when multiple users access the page, the whole web site will bug out. I believe it is losing the conneciton to the database, and i have to restart the server for it to come back online. The reservation page is the only page on the whole site that is causing this issue.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What does *bug out* mean, are there errors? What errors?

Comment: *I am using a static SqlConnection* - What do you mean by this? If rather than a factory of some kind you have a static instance of the connection then all users will try to use the same instance which will cause issues as its not thread-safe.  Create the connection as needed and let pooling take care of the optimisation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your application has [connection leak](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.100).aspx).for example u are using `dbconnection` with out using block.

Also If u are using EF Note that have to use context  with using:

```
using(var context = new MyContext("name=MyConStr")
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I am using a static SqlConnection so i dont dispose it with a using block. I am not using EF

Comment: @Lodal so you should increase max pool size in connection string